# What is the correct notation for writing events in terms of other events?

Tags: probability

In my probability and statistics class, I am confused about the notation for describing events. I'd like to use the following problem as an example:

[image]

I know what the answers are but am confused about the notation I need to use to describe them. For example, part a is $A_{ab} = [(A_1, A_2, A_3)]$ while part b is $A_{ab} = [(A_1, A_2, A_3), (A1, A2), (A1, A3)]$

Answer (score 1):

Events are sets of outcomes, so we therefore use set notation to describe their combinations.

So, the event that the three switches are all closed (ie they are in series) would be the intersection: $(A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3)$ , while the event that *at least one* among the three is closed (ie they are in parallel) would be the union: $(A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3)$.